# Python ripemd160 error

Tags: python, hashlib, ripemd

I'm trying to use the inbuilt `ripemd160` and `md4` provided by `Openssl` to generate hash.
This is my code

```
import hashlib
c = input("Enter: ")
c = c.encode('utf-8')
h = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
d = h.update(c)
print(d.hexdigest())
```

But this give me an error

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'`

Comment: general rule: if a method modifies the object inplace then it probably returns *nothing* (`None`). If it returns something then it doesn't modify input arguments e.g., `L.sort()` vs. `M = sorted(L)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update()` do not return the digest. Digest is generated by `digest()` or `hexdigest()`

```
h.update(c)
print(h.hexdigest())
```